# wsl installation with Visual Studio Code with # instead of >

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

wsl installation with Visual Studio Code!!!!!

Hi. I keep on getting this Hash in my wsl terminal on VSC "root@upstairs:~#"[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHaNK.jpg)

Shouldn't it be something like this>[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBv68.jpg)

Where am I going wrong? I've tried reinstalling several times but now I'm at lost. Many thanks before hand.

Comment: the default shell for root is `/bin/sh` and it has a prompt `#`, your title says `>` but that is for Windows terminals, the second image has a `$` prompt (user bash shell)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a different shell then.

Try switching between available terminal profiles via the dropdown in the terminal panel (see image), to find the one that you need. From there you can either choose the default profile, or create a new one by following the [tutorial in VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_configuring-profiles) (although, if both screenshots were taken on the same machine, VSCode must be able to autodetect the profile that you want).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to sit down this afternoon and give it another blast. I appreciate you quick response. Many thanks again.